# How to run multiple tool from different workspace environments

Tags: arcpy, environment-variable

I've created 1 script to perform 2 specific tasks but it not working correctly due to how the `arcpy.env.workspace` is set.

The first part of the script deletes and recreates the sub folders in `"C:/EIS/SHP Files"`

```
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/EIS/SHP Files"
```

The second part of the script looks inside a particular sub folder in "C:/EIS/SHP Files/Master folder" and copies Pipe data back into the newly created folders

```
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/EIS/SHP Files/Master Folder"
```

**Problem: I can't reference 2 environments at once in a script. The script will give out an error message since it can't look in 2 paths at once. So how can we do this?**

```
import sys
import platform
import imp
print "Importing arcpy... this may take a moment\n"
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

# Set workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/EIS/SHP Files"

# Creates the county folders
out_folder_path = "C:/EIS/SHP Files/"

# Set local variables
# List of folder values in load order
folderList = ["1","2","3","4","5"]

# Store all the folder names in a dictionary with the folder code as the  
# "key" and the folder description as the "value" (folderDict[code])
folderDict ={"1":"OH_ADAMS","2":"OH_ALLEN","3":"OH_ASHLAND","4":"OH_ASHTABULA","5":"OH_ATHENS"}

# Wayne Pipe
in_data_WayneMain =  "WayneMain.shp"
out_Geauga_WayneMain = "C:/EIS/SHP Files/OH_GEAUGA/WayneMain.shp"

# The Code below will utilize the [arcpy.CreateFolder_management] tool in 
# order to rebuild the directory for C:\EIS\SHP Files\.. County Folders

# Process: Add valid material types to the domain
# use a for loop to cycle through all the domain codes in the dictionary
for code in folderList:
    if arcpy.Exists(out_folder_path):
        arcpy.Delete_management(folderDict[code])
        arcpy.CreateFolder_management(out_folder_path, folderDict[code])

# The Code below will utilize the [arcpy.Copy_management] tool in order to   
# copy files from the C:\EIS\SHP Files\Master Folder to C:\EIS\SHP Files.. 
# County Folders

# Wayne Pipe (Copied) To => County Folders
arcpy.Copy_management(in_data_WayneMain, out_Geauga_WayneMain)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reset your environment workspace as required:

```
workspace1 = "C:/EIS/SHP Files"
workspace2 = "C:/EIS/SHP Files/Master Folder"

arcpy.env.workspace = workspace1 
#Do the stuff that requires workspace1 as the environment workspace

arcpy.env.workspace = workspace2 
#Do the stuff that requires workspace2 as the environment workspace

arcpy.env.workspace = workspace1 
#Change it back to workspace1 if it's needed again.
```

Alternatively, use the `workspace1` etc. variables instead of the environment settings to specify the relevant folders:

```
os.path.join(workspace1, in_data_WayneMain)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since ArcGIS Pro 2.8, it is possible to use `arcpy.EnvManager()` in a `with` block to temporarily set a workspace environment.

This documentation page explains how it works: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/classes/envmanager.htm